# Is there a reason I can't have a simple <script> element for the Facebook JS SDK?

Tags: facebook, iife

Facebook's documentation ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5 ) says the following snippet should be used to include their SDK in a web-page:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

The first statement just sets a field in the `window` object. The second expression is an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, but all it does is create a `<script>` element in the document immediately after the first `<script>` element in the document.

The documentation says this is "asynchronously load the SDK into" my pages, however an IIFE is executed immediately, there is nothing asynchronous about it. Why do they claim that?

Is there any reason I can't just have the element in pure HTML and placed where *I* want it in the document (like below):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};
</script>
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

And can I just add the `async="async"` boolean attribute?

Comment: The IIFE is executed immediately - but it dynamically creates a script element to load the SDK code, and that means it will load asynchronously. This code is tested and proven to work - there should be no real reason why you’d need to mess with that.

Comment: @CBroe But the IIFE sets the `src` property of the `script` element immediately. Won't that cause the browser to block when it gets the `sdk.js` file when it appends the script to the DOM?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/#toc-dom-rescue: _“Scripts that are dynamically created and added to the document are async by default, they don’t block rendering and execute as soon as they download”_